# Best way to move live site local

Tags: database, localhost

I'm trying to move a big site that's currently live onto my local machine so I can edit locally. I'm using Wamp Server. I've tried using the [Duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) but I'm getting several warnings and errors when I try to unpackage it locally. Is there a more foolproof way to do this?

Otherwise, would it be easier to move the live site onto a sub-domain on my personal site? Something like 'site.com/clients/test-site'? I just need an environment where I can make changes without affecting the live site.

Answer (score 7):

Why didn't you try to copy your live website manually. It's not as easy as using a plugin but much more error proof. You will need to follow these steps.

1. Make a dump of MYSQL database on server.

   ```
   mysqldump -u username -p -h localhost dbname > domain.sql
   ```
2. Create a archive of your WordPress website on server.

   ```
   tar -czf domain.tar.gz domain.com
   ```
3. Download both on local machine. And extract the archive.

   ```
   tar -xzf domain.tar.gz
   ```
4. Import database at local machine.

   ```
   mysql -u username -p -h localhost dbname < domain.sql
   ```
5. Now change wp-config.php values for local server.
6. Change domain name in MySQL. You can run these mysql queries to replace it with local domain setup.

   ```
   UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl.com', 'http://www.newurl.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
   UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl.com','http://www.newurl.com');
   UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl.com', 'http://www.newurl.com');
   UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl.com','http://www.newurl.com');
   ```

Or simply define these in wp-config.php, these will overwrite domain URLs in database. I think this will be better for local development.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/blog' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/blog' );
```

7. Done.

I develop and move nearly 7-10 WordPress websites each month and this is what I do. I can't say it's better than using a plugin or any other migration tool but it's more controlled. And once you get familiar with the process, there are very less chances of error.

Comment: After a couple years of working with Wordpress, this became basically my default process as well, good stuff @Roberthue.  I still used interconnectit's search and replace script for the db but that was only because it's so reliable and handled length for serialized entries too.  OP, this might all sound a bit complicated, but learning the process inside and out will make you a much better developer for your clients that need WordPress work.

Comment: @AndrewBartel thank you for mentioning. I also use [interconnectit's search and replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) script but I didn't mention it here because I did not want to scare him with another 3rd party script. And also I think nterconnectit's script has much better use for websites that you want to move. For local development purpose, defining `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` in `wp-config.php` will work fine.

Comment: This guy has it. If you're not into SSH it's doable using PHPMyAdmin to export your database.

Comment: @Joshua yes, this whole process require SSH access. And I assumed he has it because almost all hosts offer SSH access these days. :)

Comment: It's too much command line for me :P

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not as MySQL or development savvy as I would like to be. Not sure where to do this or how to start.

Comment: This is shell commands, you will need SSH access for these. If you are a developer and work on web servers then you should learn these simple tasks. Here is a [Beginner's Guide to SSH](http://www.gamexe.net/other/beginner-guide-ssh/) or [This one](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ssh-what-and-how--net-25138). You will also find many video tutorials on youtube.