# Install WordPress on new server or just copy old files?

Tags: migration, installation

Hey I move my WordPress Homepage to another server.
Now my question is, should I just copy all the files from the old server to the new server?
Or should I install WordPress on the new server and then copy the files?

Comment: You can copy files from old server to new server and then import database. Here is a [brief guide](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166905/best-way-to-move-live-site-local/166916#166916).

Answer (score 2):

I used to do this tedious manipulation manually, but I've dropped that way of migrating WP site when I discovered [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/).
This is a free plugin which will save you a lot of pain for more complex website as it will rewrite all your current url to target server, import all your widget and activate all plugins on installation.

Installation is a piece of cake. You'll do it through admin panel.

I use this plugin to migrate live website to work locally and you have a complete backup instantly as well.

Note: I don't have anything to do with this plugin. :)

Comment: I confirm, the plugin is easy to use and does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Takes 10 minutes of actual work to move sites from one server to another. Just download the site via FTP and then upload to the new server. While that's happening, export database from old server and import to new, don't forget to change wp_config is username and password and database name change. If the URL isn't changing, then there's no need to search and replace on the database, just resave permalinks to cover yourself.

Answer (score 1):

1) I would take all your wordpress "old" files and move them to your new server folder.
2) Then you will need to create a new user and database in your new server and import your old database there, and update your db connection data in wp-config.php. You probably need to export your DB before import it in the new location, you can use WP migrate DB plugin.
3) Import your modified DB to the new server.

That's all. * Make a Bkup of DB and files before proceeding.
You will find a lot info in internet about wp migrations.
Sometimes could be tricky, be sure first you understand what are you doing in every step before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UPDRAFT plugin. If you old server & new server URL different